# Android Studio - Snackbar only show at the first time in Android 4.4 and Higher Version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-design-library, android-snackbar

I created a simple QUIZ application with `Snackbar` and with `setAction`.
The `Snackbar` will show if the answer is not correct in every question.
I initialize the `Snackbar` with the bellow code:

```
Snackbar snackbar; //set the snackbar as global
View coordinatorLayoutView; // //set the coordinatorLayoutView as global

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    ...

    //Initializing coordinatorLayoutView of Snackbar
    coordinatorLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.viewCoordinate);

    //Intializing Snacbar setAction onClick listener
     final View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
                //Don't dismiss Snackbar when calling this function
            }
        };

    //Initializing Snackbar
     snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView,"Wrong Answer!",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("REVIEW", clickListener);
}
```

Then when I want to show it I just called: `snackbar.show();`
And when I want to dismiss, I just called: `snackbar.dismiss();`

When I tried running the project in `Samsung Device with Android Version 4.1.2`, the result is the expected, when I want to show the snackbar it is showing.

But when I tried it to `Other Device with Android Version 4.4 and Lollipop`, it's just showing at the first time, then when I call it again Snackbar never show anymore.

NOTE: I'm doing this in only one `Layout` and one `Activity`. The questions and answers is dynamically changing.

Also, I never called `snackbar.dismiss();` when `setAction` is clicked, but it is always dismissing when I clicked the `setAction`, how can I prevent it to dismiss?

Thank You very much for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I also face this same issue. The way I tackle it is to create a new one every time I need it.

Perhaps make this a function instead

```
Snackbar getSnackbar(Listener clickListener) {
    Return Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView,"Wrong Answer!",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("REVIEW", clickListener);
}
```

And call it to show a new one every time you need it.

```
getSnackBar(clickListener).show();
```

I hope to see a better answer on your question. If not, perhaps this could help you.

P/S: I believe the Action will always dismiss the Snackbar. This is the inherent behaviour of the Snackbar (meant to be short life). If you need something that will not dismiss after action, you might need to create your custom view doing that.